# Problemas al cargar datos utilizando numpy

Tags: python, funciones, numpy

Estoy realizando un programa en el cual al seleccionar una opcion, en este caso 0, se solicita el ingreso de datos.

```
def menu():
"Funcion para limpiar la pantalla y mostrar nuevamente el menu"
os.system('clear')
print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
print("PROGRAMA PARA CALCULOS ESTADISTICOS")
print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
print("++++++++++++++MENU++++++++++++++++++")
print("Para ingresar datos. Presione (0)")
print("Para calcular la media artimetica. Presione (1)")
print("Para calcular la mediana. Presione (2)")
print("Para calcular la moda. Presione (3)")
print("Para calcular la varianza. Presione (4)")
print("Para calcular la desviacion estandar. Presione (5)")
print("Para salir. Presione (6)")
```

Luego de haber ingresado los valores se pueden realizar todos los demas calculos.

````
```def ingreso_valores():
global datos
datos = []
n = int(input("¿Cuantos valores desea ingresar?: "))
for i in range(n):
    dato = int(input("valor: "))
    datos.append(dato)
print("Los valores ingresados son: ", datos)

def calculo_media():
media = np.mean(datos)
print("***********************************")
print("La media aritmetica es: ", media)
print("***********************************")


def calculo_mediana():
mediana = np.median(datos)
print("***********************************")
print("La mediana es: ", mediana)
print("***********************************")```
````

Pero si se selecciona directamente la opcion 1 sin carga de datos el programa arroja un error

*Seleccione una opcion >>: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Datos de usuario\Desktop\Python 3\proyecto\PROYECTO FINAL\PROYECTO_ FINAL.py", line 78, in 
calculo_media()
File "D:\Datos de usuario\Desktop\Python 3\proyecto\PROYECTO FINAL\PROYECTO_ FINAL.py", line 35, in calculo_media
media = np.mean(datos)
NameError: name 'datos' is not defined*

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Hola SrSole! Mi pregunta era de que manera evito que el programa se deje ejecutar si selecciono para que directamente se imprima cualquiera de los demás cálculos sin haber cargado inicialmente los datos. Trataría de calcular un lista vacía y me arrojaría un error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es normal que pase, mira, tú defines una función en la que creas una variable global donde guardas los datos que se ingresan por consola, el problema viene siendo que tú utilizas esa misma variable en tus otras funciones entonces si el usuario no selecciona la opción de ingresar datos esa variable llamada datos nunca se va a definir a un contexto global por lo que las otras funciones no van a operar correctamente ya que dependen de esa variable global "datos", lo que te recomiendo es que no se haga una llamada a la función de llamar datos, si no que directamente pongas al usuario a ingresar los datos y posterior se llame a las funciones que utilizan la variable datos

**EDICION**

```
import numpy as np
def menu():
    "Funcion para limpiar la pantalla y mostrar nuevamente el menu"
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    print("PROGRAMA PARA CALCULOS ESTADISTICOS")
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    print("++++++++++++++MENU++++++++++++++++++")
    print("Para ingresar datos. Presione (0)")
    print("Para calcular la media artimetica. Presione (1)")
    print("Para calcular la mediana. Presione (2)")
    print("Para calcular la moda. Presione (3)")
    print("Para calcular la varianza. Presione (4)")
    print("Para calcular la desviacion estandar. Presione (5)")
    print("Para salir. Presione (6)")

def ingreso_valores():
    n = int(input("¿Cuantos valores desea ingresar?: "))
    for i in range(n):
        dato = int(input("valor: "))
        datos.append(dato)
    print("Los valores ingresados son: ", datos)

def calculo_media():
    media = np.mean(datos)
    print("***********************************")
    print("La media aritmetica es: ", media)
    print("***********************************")


def calculo_mediana():
    mediana = np.median(datos)
    print("***********************************")
    print("La mediana es: ", mediana)
    print("***********************************")

datos = []
menu()
metodos={"0":ingreso_valores,"1":calculo_media,"2":calculo_mediana}
option=input("Ingresa tu opción")
while(option!="6"):

    if(datos or option=="0"): #true si la lista no está vacía o si la opción es 0

        metodos[option]() #llamas a la función seleccionada
    else:
        print("Primero se deben de ingresar datos")
        metodos["0"]() #llamas a la función de llenar datos
    menu()
    option = input("Ingresa tu opción")
```

Comment: Por lo que llego a entender me recomiendas que quite la función de ingreso de datos o que directamente incluya a carga de datos en cada uno de los métodos de calculo.

Comment: No, lo que te recomiendo es que primero ingreses los datos a la listar "datos" y posterior a ello ejecutes la llamada a esos métodos que utilizan dicho vector, voy a editar la respuesta para mostrarte como

Comment: Ahí lo ejecute pero al elegir tanto la opción 0 como la 1 o la 2 la consola continua diciéndome  cuantos valores deseo ingresar sin calcular ninguna de ellas :(

Comment: Copiaste y pegaste el código que te dejé?

Comment: Ahora si! Muchas gracias Alvaro y disculpa la molestia, sinceramente estoy iniciando en Python y aun me cuesta un poco. Una consulta. Los métodos son similares a las funciones en este caso? Venia usando el bucle while True pero siempre me terminaba dando error

Comment: Con gusto, estamos aquí para aprender

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta, las funciones y los métodos no son similares en este caso, un método es una funcionalidad que se le da a un objeto en específico en cambio las funciones son simplemente funcionalidades que no hacen parte de ningún objeto y se definen por sí solas, no a través de una instancia de clase